# pagination- load data on click or hide unnecessary data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pagination

I have a database table which is to be shown in a part of a webpage. The table information should be shown with pagination where each page has 5 rows.
Now, I have two options-

**1**.Load all the table into HTML (I'm using PHP here) at pageload and hide all the rows except the 5 rows that are to be shown each time.

**2**.Each time a page number is clicked, do an SQL query using AJAX. The query will fetch the exact 5 rows corresponding to the page number that is clicked.

I have seen many codes on the net following the second one. But i would still like to know that Which option would be better to use when we have specific conditions like-
**a**. Number of rows of the table could vary.
**b**. The number of simultaneous users is high.(Would that affect the database server speed?) 
**c**. Internet speed on the user side is slow.

Now, considering these situations, which option will give the best experience to the user? Is one of these options universally superior than the other?

I'm still new to web development so all help and corrections are welcome!

Comment: Please share some code here

Comment: I don't have a problem or an error in my code, I just want to know which way would be better. Both options work, but which one works better and why? that is the question here.